# Insert Multiple Records Into MySQL from a multi line table PHP Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Im having an issue adding multiple Records into MySQL. I know i am missing something simple but i cant figure it out. hence this post...Every thing is working expect for the issue when the user clicks submit. only the last row of the table is being recognized.

Example...First 2 rows have Unit Number 1234-01,1234-02 and the last row has Unit Number 1234-03. when submit is clicked it is skipping over the 01 and 02 and only entering the 03 into the database.

Thank you for any help....My head is starting to hurt from banging it on my desk.

```
<h2>Please fill in the information below</h2>
<form action="pmUnitCreate.php" method="post">
<p>Click the Add button to add a new row. Click the Delete button to Delete last row.</p>

<table id="myTable">
    <th>Unit Number</th>
    <th>Model Number</th>
    <th>Serial Number</th>
    <th>Scope</th>
    <th><input type="button" id="btnAdd" class="button-add" onClick="insertRow()" value="Add"></input></th>
    <th><input type="button" id="btnDelete" class="button-delete" onClick="deleteRow(-1)" value="Delete"></input></th>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="UnitID" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="ModelNumber" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="SerialNumber" /></td>
        <td><select name="Scope">

                <option value="BTank">BTank</option>
                <option value="WSEcon">WSEcon</option>
                <option value="NetPkg">NetPkg</option>
                <option value="CstmCabinet">CstmCabinet</option>
                <option value="CstmCtrl">CstmCtrl</option>
                <option value="CstmRef">CstmRef</option>
                <option value="CstmSM">CstmSM</option>
                <option value="CstmHV">CstmHV</option>
                <option value="CPCtrl">CPCtrl</option>
                <option value="DesiHW">DesiHW</option>
                <option value="DigScroll">DigScroll</option>
                <option value="DFGas">DFGas</option>
                <option value="DWall">DWall</option>
                <option value="MZ-DD">MZ-DD</option>
                <option value="DPP">DPP</option>
                <option value="Encl">Encl</option>
                <option value="PlateHX">PlateHX</option>
                <option value="ERW">ERW</option>

                </select>
                </td>



    </tr>

<br>

<script>

var index = 1;
function insertRow(){
            var table=document.getElementById("myTable");
            var row=table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
            var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
            var t1=document.createElement("input");
                t1.name = "UnitID";
                cell1.appendChild(t1);
            var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
            var t2=document.createElement("input");
                t2.id = "ModelNumber";
                cell2.appendChild(t2);
            var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
            var t3=document.createElement("input");
                t3.id = "SerialNumber";
                cell3.appendChild(t3);
            var cell4=row.insertCell(3);
            var element2 = document.createElement("select");
                element2.id="Scope";
                //element2.type = "select";
    var option1 = document.createElement("option");
        option1.innerHTML = "BTank";
            option1.value = "1";
            element2.add(option1, null);
    var option2 = document.createElement("option");
        option2.innerHTML = "WSEcon";
        option2.value = "2";
        element2.add(option2, null);
    var option3 = document.createElement("option");
        option3.innerHTML = "NetPkg";
            option3.value = "3";
            element2.add(option3, null);
        var option4 = document.createElement("option");
        option4.innerHTML = "CstmCtrl";
            option4.value = "4";
            element2.add(option4, null);
        var option5 = document.createElement("option");
        option5.innerHTML = "CstmRef";
            option5.value = "5";
            element2.add(option5, null);
        var option6 = document.createElement("option");
        option6.innerHTML = "CstmSM";
            option6.value = "6";
            element2.add(option6, null);
        var option7 = document.createElement("option");
        option7.innerHTML = "CstmHV";
            option7.value = "7";
            element2.add(option7, null);        


        cell4.appendChild(element2);

      index++;

}

function deleteRow(){
document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(-1);

}
```

Here is the SQL code

```
<?php
//initialize and read the variables from the posting
//include('Mail.php');
$UnitID=$_POST['UnitID'];
 $UnitID="'" . $UnitID . "'";  //Adds the required quotation marks
$ModelNumber=$_POST['ModelNumber'];
 $ModelNumber="'" . $ModelNumber . "'";  //Adds the required quotation marks
$SerialNumber=$_POST['SerialNumber'];
 $SerialNumber="'" . $SerialNumber . "'";  //Adds the required quotation  marks
$Scope=$_POST['Scope'];
 $Scope="'" . $Scope . "'";  //Adds the required quotation marks

echo $UnitID; 
echo $ModelNumber;
echo $SerialNumber;
echo $Scope;

echo $UnitID;
echo $ModelNumber;
echo $SerialNumber; 
echo $Scope;

echo $UnitID;
echo $ModelNumber;
echo $SerialNumber;
echo $Scope;



//Connect to the database
include('pmconnect.php');

$sql = "INSERT INTO `tblUnitMaster` (`UnitID`, `ModelNumber`,  'SerialNumber`, `Scope`) VALUES ($UnitID, $ModelNumber, $SerialNumber, $Scope )";
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tblUnitMaster` (`UnitID`, `ModelNumber`, `SerialNumber`, `Scope`) VALUES ($UnitID, $ModelNumber, $SerialNumber, $Scope )";
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tblUnitMaster` (`UnitID`, `ModelNumber`, `SerialNumber`, `Scope`) VALUES ($UnitID, $ModelNumber, $SerialNumber, $Scope )";



if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE)

echo "<h3>Record Created Successfully.</h3><br>";

?>enter code here
```

Comment: You are overwriting `$sql`. You should be appending with `.=` and make sure each query has its own `;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting `$sql` ***(and other variables, are you performing a loop?)*** and so it only inserts the last one. A little concatenation and making sure each query has its own semi-colon will fix things up:

```
//Connect to the database
include('pmconnect.php');

$sql = "INSERT INTO `tblUnitMaster` (`UnitID`, `ModelNumber`,  'SerialNumber`, `Scope`) VALUES ($UnitID, $ModelNumber, $SerialNumber, $Scope );";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO `tblUnitMaster` (`UnitID`, `ModelNumber`, `SerialNumber`, `Scope`) VALUES ($UnitID, $ModelNumber, $SerialNumber, $Scope );";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO `tblUnitMaster` (`UnitID`, `ModelNumber`, `SerialNumber`, `Scope`) VALUES ($UnitID, $ModelNumber, $SerialNumber, $Scope )";
```

Comment: That's what i thought at first as well but that makes no difference. still skips over the first rows and only inserts the last row.

Comment: It is because you're not looping through data, so consequently only one set of variables is populated.

Comment: May seem like a dumb question but how does one loop a sql statement like that? Sorry relatively new to sql.

Comment: When you echo out the $UnitID do you see three values? You're only sending one set of values to the SQL.

Comment: No there is only 1 value when i echo the $UnitID

Comment: The form is sending only one - how are you creating the other values?

Comment: That's what the issue is the user clicks the ADD button to add another set of rows to the table. When Submit is clicked only 1 row from the table is being entered into the DB. See my original post for the Javascript code.

Comment: What is the JS supposed to be doing? It's not clear.

Comment: The JS is adding an additional row every time the user clicks the ADD button.

Comment: It is creating duplicate ID's? You cannot have duplicate ID's in an HTML page. It screws everything up if you do. What does the actual generated HTML look like?

Answer (score 0):

It is because the `@SQL` variable is being overwritten by your code. Either you need to use a different variable name or try inserting multiple rows:

```
Insert table TABLE (A,B)
Values (1,1) ,(2,2),(3,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Image of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRVBr.png)

here is a clip of the JS with the +indexing

```
<script>

var index = 1;
function insertRow(){
            var table=document.getElementById("myTable");
            var row=table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
            var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
            var t1=document.createElement("input");
                t1.name = "UnitID"+index;
                cell1.appendChild(t1);
            var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
            var t2=document.createElement("input");
                t2.id = "ModelNumber"+index;
                cell2.appendChild(t2);
            var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
            var t3=document.createElement("input");
                t3.id = "SerialNumber"+index;
                cell3.appendChild(t3);
            var cell4=row.insertCell(3);
            var element2 = document.createElement("select");
                element2.id="Scope"+index;
                //element2.type = "select";
    var option1 = document.createElement("option");
        option1.innerHTML = "BTank";
            option1.value = "1";
            element2.add(option1, null);
    var option2 = document.createElement("option");
        option2.innerHTML = "WSEcon";
        option2.value = "2";
        element2.add(option2, null);
    var option3 = document.createElement("option");
        option3.innerHTML = "NetPkg";
            option3.value = "3";
            element2.add(option3, null);
        var option4 = document.createElement("option");
        option4.innerHTML = "CstmCtrl";
            option4.value = "4";
            element2.add(option4, null);
        var option5 = document.createElement("option");
        option5.innerHTML = "CstmRef";
            option5.value = "5";
            element2.add(option5, null);
        var option6 = document.createElement("option");
        option6.innerHTML = "CstmSM";
            option6.value = "6";
            element2.add(option6, null);
        var option7 = document.createElement("option");
        option7.innerHTML = "CstmHV";
            option7.value = "7";
            element2.add(option7, null);        


        cell4.appendChild(element2);

      index++;

}

function deleteRow(){
document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(-1);

}

</script>
```